# My SQL Python ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000)

Tags: python, mysql, sql, database, scrapy

I am trying to store scraped data with scrapy to a sql database but I get the following error: ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 7

Please find my pipelines.py bellow

```
from datetime import datetime
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import errorcode

class LecturesinparisPipeline(object):
    ...
class CleaningPipeline(object):
    ...

class DatabasePipeline(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.create_connection()
        self.create_table()

    def create_connection(self):
        self.conn = mysql.connector.connect(
            host='localhost',
            user='root',
            passwd='sTUDIO987',
            database='lecturesinparis_db'
        )
        self.curr = self.conn.cursor()

    def create_table(self):
        self.curr.execute("""DROP TABLE IF EXISTS mdl""")
        self.curr.execute("""create table mdl(
                        title text,
                        location text,
                        startdatetime text,
                        lenght text,
                        description text,
                        )""")

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        self.store_db(item)
        return item

    def store_db(self, item):
        self.curr.execute("""insert into mdl values (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)""", (
            item['title'][0],
            item['location'][0],
            item['startdatetime'][0],
            item['lenght'][0],
            item['description'][0]
        ))
        self.conn.commit()
```

Comment: Please show the full traceback, or tell us which of those queries the message pertains to.

Comment: You gave us your class but you did not show the code you actually ran

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a coma too much,

use instead

```
def create_table(self):
    self.curr.execute("""DROP TABLE IF EXISTS mdl""")
    self.curr.execute("""create table mdl(
                    title text,
                    location text,
                    startdatetime text,
                    lenght text,
                    description text
                    )""")
```